# React native Base64 encoding string

Tags: react-native, base64

I am trying to use the base-64 library from

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/base64

When I run a test to validate the code I am not getting the right result. IS there any other library I can use?

Here is the code that I ran and the result I am getting

```
import utf8 from 'utf8'
import base64 from 'base-64'

var text = 'foo © bar  baz';
var bytes = utf8.encode(text);
var encoded = base64.encode(bytes);
console.log(encoded);
// → 'Zm9vIMKpIGJhciDwnYyGIGJheg=='
```

Here is the result I am getting

W29iamVjdCBBcnJheUJ1ZmZlcl0=

Can some one please help

thanks in advance

Comment: utf8 module in react-native is returning ArrayBuffer. base64 module expects a string.

Comment: follow this thread: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js/issues/17

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485527/a-replacement-for-binarytobase64-that-can-be-used-in-react-native

Answer (score 14, accepted):

React Native has a [binaryToBase64 util](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/Utilities/binaryToBase64.js) that accepts ArrayBuffer for base64 conversions:

```js
var utf8 = require('utf8');
var binaryToBase64 = require('binaryToBase64');

var text = 'foo © bar  baz';
var bytes = utf8.encode(text);
var encoded = binaryToBase64(bytes);
console.log(encoded);
// Zm9vIMKpIGJhciDwnYyGIGJheg==
```

You might need to install the `utf8` package, since it was [removed from React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17146) in version 0.54:

```
npm install --save utf8
```

Comment: how to get utf-8 from base64 string?

Answer (score 21):

I think you don't need to use any third-party package for it.

The example below is working in React-Native:

```js
    const Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;
    let encodedAuth = new Buffer("your text").toString("base64");
```

Comment: I don't think it's available in pure React Native, neither it's claimed to work. It might be available in expo or rn-nodeify based projects, more context is here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14796

Comment: rn-nofeify and BufferJS make Buffer work in React-Native. Expo does not help with that. Using it currently.

Comment: I'm running react-native `0.70.6` and this works without installing any `npm` packages. I'm hopping the API is pretty close to the one of NodeJS `Buffer` because I'm not really sure where this package comes from or how to find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 15):

*Comments state the accepted answer now works as of `RN@0.60.3`:*

Neither the accepted answer nor the Buffer methods worked for me. Here's what worked as of **January 2019**:

```
yarn add react-native-base64
```

then

```
import base64 from 'react-native-base64'
base64.encode('Some string to encode to base64');
```

Comment: What is your react native version? Because this other answer works for me (`v0.60.3`) and doesnt require additional dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52949986/4852737

Comment: I was on `v0.57.8` then. If the Buffer answer works now that's great!

Comment: Can you please check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74243509/how-to-support-special-characters-react-natvie-base-64?noredirect=1#comment131078029_74243509 may you have any suggestions. 
Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Tested and working in React Native v0.66.1

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'
    
export function toBase64(input) {
  return Buffer.from(input, 'utf-8').toString('base64')
}

export function fromBase64(encoded) {
  return Buffer.from(encoded, 'base64').toString('utf8')
}
```

Comment: `Error: undefined Unable to resolve module buffer` RN 0.67.1. [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) package needs to be installed first; you're probably having it available because some other package you've got installed may be using it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any extra library. Just use:

```
let encodedCredentials = new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this package.
This small library has 2 functions encode and decode and both accepts strings.
This is a good replacement for the btoa and atob on the borowser.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-base64

Comment: Is this really a replacement to binaryToBase64? Looking at react-native-base64, it has a function that converts a string to base64 and a function that does the opposite, but not binaryToBase64...

Comment: @Yossi you are right it's not dealing with binaries. This package comes to help when needed to convert text (tested on latin text) to base64 and vice versa in the most simple way, with small size of code.

Comment: If you like, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485527/a-replacement-for-binarytobase64-that-can-be-used-in-react-native

Answer (score 1):

I got an error when I tried to use `Buffer` because it was deprecated. I did this:

```js
const TOKEN = btoa(clientId + ':' + secret);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [base-64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64) and [utf8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8)

(which are more broadly used than the rn library above - and support utf8 characters)

to base64 encode/decode on our react-native app. I don't see why that has to be react-native specific, it's just javascript, and it works.

`npm install base-64 utf8;`

and then here's what my code looks like:

```js
        import base64 from 'base-64';
        import utf8 from 'utf8';
        const SALT = 'anyString';
        const PREPENDING_STR = '__enc__';

        function encodeCredential(input) {
            if (input // if the input exists
                && typeof input === 'string' // and it's a string
            ) {
                const newInput = `${input}${SALT}`; // add salt to the input
                const utf8Bytes = utf8.encode(newInput); // utf8 encode it
                const encoded = base64.encode(utf8Bytes); // base64 encode it

                return `${PREPENDING_STR}${encoded}`; // add a prepending string
            }

            return input;
        }

        function decodeCredential(input) {
            if (input // if the input exists
                && typeof input === 'string' // and it's a string
                && input.startsWith(PREPENDING_STR) === true // and it's encoded yet
            ) {
                const newInput = input.replace(PREPENDING_STR, ''); // remove the prepending string
                const utf8Bytes = base64.decode(newInput); // base64 decode it
                const output = utf8.decode(utf8Bytes); // utf8 decode it

                return output.replace(SALT, '');
            }

            return input;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const encodeBase64 = (input) => {  
    const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';  
    let str = input;
    let output = '';

    for (let block = 0, charCode, i = 0, map = chars;
      str.charAt(i | 0) || (map = '=', i % 1);
      output += map.charAt(63 & block >> 8 - i % 1 * 8)) {

    charCode = str.charCodeAt(i += 3/4);

    if (charCode > 0xFF) {
      console.log("'btoa' failed: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.");
    }
  
    block = block << 8 | charCode;
  }

  return output;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rn-fetch-blob to do the conversion in native code :

```js
import { fs } from 'rn-fetch-blob';
    
export const blobToBase64 = async (data, encoding = 'base64') => fs.readFile(data, encoding);
```