# Arabic text not rendered correctly (rendered as rubbish)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am working on a [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) app and I have a problem when rendering some Arabic text that returned from API  most of the times the text looks like rubbish (check screenshot 1)

And for a few times, it rendered correctly (check screenshot 2)

screenshot 1
[image: screenshot 1]

screenshot 2
[image: screenshot 2]

I checked the API response and it always returns the text correctly.

FYI I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to fetch the data.

## EDIT

Here is my axios code :

```
const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Accept: "application/json"
};

const requestBody = {
  msgUID: getMsgUID(),
  uid: this.props.user.uid
};

axios
  .post(Config.FETCH_VISITS_URL, requestBody, { headers: headers })
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      arrayOfVisits: response.visits
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(
      "Error getting documnets",
      error + " msgUID " + requestBody.msgUID
    );
  });
```

## EDIT 2

Here is the API response:

```
{
    "msgUID": "654894984984",
    "responseTime": 1567253177771,
    "size": 4,
    "visits": [{
            "visitExitTimestamp": "",
            "changeHistory": [],
            "entryType": {
                "vehicleDetails": {},
                "by": ""
            },
            "createdBy": "fz085jMMedPApY0tp9L1e7iqyfO2",
            "visitEntryTimestamp": "",
            "visitStatus": "new",
            "visitTypeObject": {
                "lastName": "السيد",
                "durationAmount": "30",
                "firstName": "علي",
                "phoneNumber": "(123) 456 - 7890",
                "notes": "Test",
                "durationType": "days",
                "type": "person"
            },
            "timestampFrom": "2019-08-28T16:56:00.000Z",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "key": "oTAJ8WbVh54tVaemVoz6",
            "createTime": "2019-08-27T16:56:45.286Z",
            "checkInTime": "",
            "checkOutTime": ""
        },
        {
            "visitExitTimestamp": "",
            "changeHistory": [],
            "entryType": {
                "vehicleDetails": {},
                "by": ""
            },
            "createdBy": "fz085jMMedPApY0tp9L1e7iqyfO2",
            "visitEntryTimestamp": "",
            "visitStatus": "new",
            "visitTypeObject": {
                "lastName": "",
                "durationAmount": "30",
                "firstName": "محمد",
                "phoneNumber": "(123) 456 - 7890",
                "notes": "Test",
                "durationType": "days",
                "type": "person"
            },
            "timestampFrom": "2019-08-28T16:46:00.000Z",
            "isDeleted": false,
            "key": "oTAJ8WbVh54tVaemVoz6",
            "createTime": "2019-08-27T16:46:45.286Z",
            "checkInTime": "",
            "checkOutTime": ""
        }
    ],
    "status": 200,
    "statusString": "OK"
}
```

below you can find the render method that I am using:

```
renderVisitorName(firstName,lastName) {
      return (
        <Text style={styles.name}>
          {firstName + " " + lastName}
        </Text>
      );
}
```

I am only testing this on [Android](https://www.android.com/).

Comment: did you check the output of the API? it could be using some Encoding other than UTF-8

Comment: @whd.nsr yes I've checked it and it always returns Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8 ,,, the weird thing is why sometimes it works correctly?

Comment: Just as a question: Did you check this in different phones or tried using emulators. Sometimes this can be a font issue when react-native doesn't support some characters.

Comment: @GauravMall Yes i did, i used different physical and emulated devices. If it is font related why sometimes the text  renders correctly ?

Comment: well, could depend on react-native. Try opening an issue on github. You know as I don't know arabic, I don't know why this could happen. Everything points to a unicode bug, but nothing is decisive yet.

Comment: Does the font you're using include all of the glyphs for the arabic text?

Comment: @LeeBrindley i did not change the font , i am using the default react-native font; FYI i have tried to add some static Arabic text and this text always rendered correctly , so the issue is only with the text that returns from the API (btw i am using axios to call the api) and i make sure that the response always retruns Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8. thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: can you share your axios code?

Comment: 1.Does the first package of the HTTP request is always good and only then it starts to mixture? 
2. Do u use anything that enabled HTTP breadcrumbs? tools like Santry or Newrelic?

Comment: Please add the data you have fetched from the api.

Comment: @MohammedAlawneh I had similar problems with burmese characters. Does a specific text always render correctly or badly? (ie: is it limited to specific characters?) Is your font weight always the same? I had issues only with bold fonts for some reason.

Comment: @Gowtham please find the code under the edit in the question above.

Comment: @gran33 1. No, the first HTTP request is not always good. 2. I am not using anything to enable HTTP breadcrumbs. I am not using any tools.

Comment: @Tim Do you want the API response? anyway, it's added to the question above under EDIT 2.

Comment: @LaurentS It's not about a specific text, this happens randomly. Regarding the font-weight yes it's always the same, actually yes now I am using a bold font, but after testing this occurs to all font weights and types.

Comment: I suggest to use the Arabic font for such a ui which rendering Arabic text.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess on a UTF handling problem to.
Please check the following thread, maybe you have the same issue:

[react-native-base64-encoding-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255154/react-native-base64-encoding-string/51448951)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a character encoding issue. Your issue could be solved with a package `utf8`. It will help you a lot when you are working with utf8 text. The error is just because of your font does not support Arabic language and hence it returns weird characters.

First, install the `utf8` package in your project as,

```
npm i --save utf8
```

Another important thing is if you are using custom `font-face` in react native, make sure your font is supported for the language you are using. You can use a combination of fonts as well. Similar issues found with languages such as,
• Chinese
• Hebrew
• Hindi
• Japanese
• Korean

But still, you can overcome the issue by using custom fonts and encoding as utf8. You can find Arabic fonts [Here](https://www.fontsc.com/font/tag/arabic). Set it up as `font-family` from you react-native stylesheet and then give it a try.

`dart:convert` package has encode/decode functions available, you'll need it if the API returns encoded text. You can use it as,

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
var encoded = utf8.encode('Text');
var decoded = utf8.decode(encoded);
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell me some fonts for Chinese text? I am having a problem with Chinese text and can't find any relevant font

Comment: You need Unicode Chinese fonts. Maybe you can find some here https://cooltext.com/Fonts-Unicode-Chinese , I didn't use Chinese fonts ever. You can choose best font based on trial and error method.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was not clear for me. But I found the place where the thing went wrong.
So, wherever you are saving the text to the database or sending to the server, just encode before sending the text using `utf8`:

First install `utf8`:

`yarn add utf8` or `npm i --save utf8`

then encode like so,

```
import utf8 from 'utf8';
...


utf8.encode(mytext);
```

There is no need to `decode` and no issue with `fonts` (at least in my case).

Just render the text again, and it should work.