# A replacement for binaryToBase64 that can be used in react-native

Tags: react-native, base64

I have been using react-native's binaryToBase64, but it doesn't exist in new react-native versions (such as 0.62.2).
Any suggestion on what to use instead?

I tried js btoa(), but results are different, any idea why?

### For example:

#### btoa

let output = btoa(input);

input: Uint8Array(5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
output: MCwxLDIsMyw0

input: Uint8Array(5) [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
output: NSw2LDcsOCw5

#### binaryToBase64

let output = binaryToBase64(input);

input: Uint8Array(5) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
output: AAECAwQ=

input: Uint8Array(5) [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
output: BQYHCAk=

Comment: *but results are different* - can you pls. show an example with input and the different outputs?

Comment: @jps Added examples to the question

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29195#issuecomment-648157628). Thanks, [EyMaddis](https://github.com/EyMaddis)!

> This is now more aligned with the rest of the JS ecosystem: base64.js:

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

export function toBase64(input) {
  return Buffer.from(input, 'utf-8').toString('base64')
}

export function fromBase64(encoded) {
  return Buffer.from(encoded, 'base64').toString('utf8')
}
```