# react native svg string to base64 format

Tags: reactjs, svg, base64, native

I need to base64 encode a SVG string. I want to write a function for it. I searched for available packages but there are none for working on react native. I also tried to firstly convert an image, like png or jpeg and after that convert to base64 but there are no available package for that either.

In react, is it possible, because I found this repo but I can't refactor it for react native.

https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Please help about typescipt because I am working on typescript template for react native.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to base64 encode svgs since they are xml based and not binary. The linked yoksel encoder just strips whitespace and replaces some characters like `#` with `%23`. You may convert this javascript helper to typescript. Check this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/KKEWwmK?editors=1010) - helper function`sanitizeSvgMarkup()`. Otherwise you find [other posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255154/react-native-base64-encoding-string) discussing this topic.